# Is there a way to have Teams auto-complete email addresses outside your domain?

Tags: office365, autocomplete, microsoft-teams

I am the Microsoft 365 admin of my (small) organization. We have Teams meetings these days, mostly with people outside the org (gmail/etc addresses). I have added all these email addresses to the [Exchange admin center](https://outlook.office365.com/ecp/?rfr=Admin_o365&exsvurl=1&mkt=en-US) as **Mail contacts**, and even added them to my personal Exchange account, but I cannot get these addresses to auto-complete when I create a new Teams meeting, like what happens with internal email addresses - I have to repeatedly manually enter all of them for each new meeting. Our Teams meetings otherwise work just fine. There are **Contacts** in Teams, but I can't add email addresses there - only phone numbers. (And after the meeting is over, if I go back and look at the list of attendees in Teams, their names from Exchange have been populated!)

Is there any way to add these addresses somewhere, or turn on some feature, so I can more easily enter the addresses during meeting creation?

Comment: Addresses will add to the local Autocomplete as Users use the address to email people.

Comment: @John in Outlook, but not (for me, at least) in Teams

Comment: Autocomplete is normally a local and user thing. So each user needs to manage their own email addresses.

Comment: @John if the addresses are in the GC they should be usable in Teams, no?

Comment: In most cases, the users must manage addresses themselves.  I am not certain about the interaction with Teams.